# Content aware patching while keeping Smartobject?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

> **TL;DR** How do I use Content aware patching while keeping the layer as Smartobject?

I'm currently creating a poster for cake selling of my school

I'm a huge fan of working on Smartobjects only. Sadly I wanted to content-aware-patch the background so it matches for the poster format. (See below)

[image]
[image]

The quality of these images is sufficient for my school but I'd like to increase the quality of it by copying it very actively as a human without needing Photoshop to guess what to do.

I used the Content Aware Filling from `Edit` > `Fill` (`Shift` + `F5`)

This sadly removes my Smartobject which leads to my question:
How do I use Content aware patching without removing the Smartobject?

I know about the patching tool stated [in this article](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/content-aware-patch-move.html) but this doesn't work on Smartobjects either.
I also know about the Camera RAW-Editor which includes the Pimple-Removal-Tool but the outcome of that tool isn't very good. (I dont know the english name of the tool)

I hope someone of you knows knows how to extend the cake image the way I did but in Smartobjects so I can go back if I make a mistake. The cake topping in the background is removed which shows you that the method used by me is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I follow your question but I believe this is the answer. Feel free to leave a comment if I'm wrong and I'll either edit or delete this:

Create a new layer above your Smart Object and then when using the Patch Tool select "Sample All Layers" as shown here:

[image: Sample All Layers]

It should sample from Smart Layers, Raster Layers, Vectors, everything. In general this is good practice for any sort of Cloning/Patching Tools since its non-destructive to your original layer... or in your case Smart Layer.

Comment: Yea it's a good answer but I still wait until i teceive something better as answer. I'll mark your as answer when you are the best answer I will receive

Comment: @JonasDralle Why is my answer not 100% what you're after? What is it not accomplishing that you'd still like to be able to do?

Comment: I'd like to edit directly on the smartobject. I do not know if this is possible in any way. I just want to wait to see some other approaches

Comment: If you're using a Photo anyways than it didn't start out as a Smart Object so why not just do your Transformations and Patching before converting it to a Smart Object then? @JonasDralle

Comment: First of all: It's habit of me I consider as healthy. Secondly when I rescale the image I would loose pixels every time I resize. I'm not loosibg any pixels when using smartobjects because the image infornation is saved in an extern adobe document